# Why is Excel SaveAs() argument xlLocalSessionChanges not working in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to use PowerShell to save file.xlsx as file.txt and overwrite the existing file without prompt.

Code:

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$Filename = "file"
$AbsFilePathNoExt=(Get-Item .).FullName+"\"+$Filename
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($AbsFilePathNoExt+".xlsx")
$dft=[Type]::Missing
$wb.SaveAs($AbsFilePathNoExt+".txt",
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlUnicodeText,
$dft,
$dft,
$dft,
$dft,
$dft,
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution]::xlLocalSessionChanges)
$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()
```

The 8th argument of SaveAs is xlLocalSessionChanges, which should make Excel overwrite the existing file without prompt. But window still prompts when saving. Why is xlLocalSessionChanges not working?

[Excel Workbook.SaveAs Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Environment: Windows 10. Excel 365. PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Try adding `$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false` before the SaveAs.

Comment: Or forget about all that and use `$wb.Close($true)`